# Is there a way to use a SetState to change the index of my Api data?

Tags: flutter, api

im trying to use a api to show up the data and im using a global var who is set by 1 to navigate from data, like this `var uri = Uri.parse('https://ffxivcollect.com/api/spells/${globals.x}');`

and the hard thing is that i want to show all the values with that, going from 1 to 100.
what i tried to do was:

```
body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: finalApi!.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return MaterialButton(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(finalApi![globals.x].name),
              ],
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                globals.x++;
              });
            },
          );
        },
      ),
```

```
library globalx.globals;

int x = 1;
```

But then i got a index error. I tried with other methods too, like a for, but then just the first name shows up and dont change.

sorry if it is a simple thing, im still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the index, not a global variable. Let's say your list has 100 items, then the itemBuilder function is called 100 times and on each pass each index is taken (0-99)

```
Text(finalApi![index].name),
```

Comment: i used that. my problem was my json, but now i cant show the name and others things. my api file now has query, count and results in the main class, the data that i want should be in results wich is a list, but there is no code to do that i guess, what i tried was  Text(finalApi![index].results.first.toString());